# Segment Control Issue in cornerradius in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am developing an app in which I want to use segmented control with a radius corner.
With `setCornerRadius` and `setBorderColor`, I have set corner radius and color.

But problem is Its looks as below image.

I have `setbackgroundColor` of segmented control as clear color.

But it is not working.

[image: Segement Image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `clipsToBounds` property to `YES`